# How to stop Rails Admin from truncating a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have a rails_admin model config as follows:

```
rails_admin do
  list do
    field :summary
  end
end
```

And `summary` is a custom method in my model that basically just returns a very long text:

```
def summary
  first_name + last_name + ':\n' + bio 
end
```

What I'm having trouble with is that this text gets truncated in the list view, and my `\n` newline characters doesn't render into actual new lines.

I basically want to print the entire long text, without truncation in the list view, and have line breaks that I defined. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try to do it in a different way like this:
change the new line `\n` with a line brake `<br>` then return it as HTML safe.

```
def summary
  (first_name + last_name + '<br>' + bio).html_safe
end
```

Comment: I am glad I could help